# Assigning functions as properties of a prototyped function

Tags: javascript

Is it bad practice, in javascript, to assign a function as a property of a function that can also ne used as a class. A simple example will talk for itself:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.myVar = 1;
}
MyClass.prototype.printMyVar = function() {
    MyClass.printerUtil(this.myVar);
};

MyClass.printerUtil = function(text) {
    console.log(text);
};
```

In this example, should `MyClass.printerUtil` be declared in its own container (`MyUtils.printerUtil`) or is it OK to do it like that ?
Do you know any relevand documentation/article I could read ?

Comment: I am quite convinced this is not bad but I have this college pretending that this is the devil's way of doing things and I need to convince myself I'm right before I can confront him. A reference would be most welcome. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

No it's okay just make sure you don't use `this` as it was an instance method, it acts like a static method.

---

More generally, you can also store variables in classes, for instance if you wanted to keep trace of how many times a text has been printed (this code is only for demonstration purpose, you should probably do it diffrently in a production environment)

```
MyClass.printerUtil = function(text) {
    console.log(text);
    MyClass.printCount++;
};

MyClass.printCount = 0;
```